# Insertion Sort Doubly Link List Issues

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

Sometimes when I run this code, a null reference exception occurs on the `Current.Next.Data = Hold.Data;`.

```
   private void InsertionSort()
    {
        for (Node FirstUnsorted = _Head.Next; FirstUnsorted != null; FirstUnsorted = FirstUnsorted.Next)
        {
            Node Hold = FirstUnsorted;
            Node Current;

            for (Current = FirstUnsorted.Prev; Current != null && Current.Data.CompareTo(Hold.Data) > 0; Current = Current.Prev)
                Current.Next.Data = Current.Data;

            Current.Next.Data = Hold.Data;
        }
    }
```

I'm aware that you cannot reference the next node if the current node is equal to null, however I'm unable to determine a solution. 
How can I prevent this issue from occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the data would be inserted first in the list, `Current` will be null. The check `Current != null` is what's ending the loop when you look for the place to insert the data.

Check for a null reference that will tell you to put the data in the first item:

```
if (Current == null) {
  _Head.Next.Data = Hold.Data;
} else {
  Current.Next.Data = Hold.Data;
}
```

You can also let `Current` point to the node where the data should end up instead of the node before it:

```
for (Current = FirstUnsorted; Current.Prev != null && Current.Prev.Data.CompareTo(Hold.Data) > 0; Current = Current.Prev) {
  Current.Data = Current.Prev.Data;
}
Current.Data = Hold.Data;
```

Side note: You are shuffling data around in the list to insert data at the corret place, when the natural thing would be to insert the node in the correct place instead. You are using the linked list as if it was just an array where you would need to move the data to make place for the insert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check, that `Current.Next != null` (the same chech is already exists for `Current`, so you understand this logic). Try this:

```
   private void InsertionSort()
   {
        for (Node FirstUnsorted = _Head.Next; FirstUnsorted != null; FirstUnsorted = FirstUnsorted.Next)
        {
            Node Hold = FirstUnsorted;
            Node Current;

            for (Current = FirstUnsorted.Prev; Current != null && Current.Next != null && Current.Data.CompareTo(Hold.Data) > 0; Current = Current.Prev)
                Current.Next.Data = Current.Data;

            if (Current.Next != null)
                Current.Next.Data = Hold.Data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the `Current` is equal to null, you can't check if the `Current.Next` is null or not, as Current.Next doesn't exist.

Comment: Just skipping the move will drop data from the list and cause duplicate references.

Comment: @TheAuzzieJesus, yes, it is true. Great, that you understand it! We check `Current.Next` only after checking of `Current`, because we don't want to have null dereference error.

Comment: @Guffa, you are right! My idea was to help OP to avoid this null dereference exception. And after this fix I was going to help him to debug and find way to have correct algorithm.